# HQL unexpected AST node: :

Tags: java, hql

My code is failing to inject the below repository.  Based on the stack trace, it seems my HQL syntax is invalid, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

```
@Repository
 public interface JobSetRepository extends JpaRepository<JobSetEntity, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE JobSetEntity SET workstation = :workstation, workflowProcess = :workstation.workflowProcess WHERE id = :jobSet.id")
    public Boolean updateWorkstation(@Param("jobSet") JobSetEntity jobSet, @Param("workstation") Workstation workstation);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE JobSetEntity SET workflowProcess = :workflowProcess, workstation = null WHERE id = :jobSet.id")
    public Boolean updateWorkflowProcess(@Param("jobSet") JobSetEntity jobSet, @Param("workflowProcess") WorkflowProcess workflowProcess);
}
```

stack trace:

```
12:57:58,692 ERROR main org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter:54 - <AST>:1:111: unexpected AST node: :
12:57:58,693 ERROR main org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter:50 - <AST>:1:111: unexpected AST node: :
<AST>:1:111: unexpected AST node: :
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4680)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExprLhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5114)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4575)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.newValue(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1211)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.assignment(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1033)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.setClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:747)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
```

**Update:** I'm also getting this error with this query:

```
@Query("UPDATE OrderEntity SET inProduction = :order.inProduction WHERE OrderEntity.id = :order.id")
void updateInProduction(@Param("order") OrderEntity order);
```

I updated my versions to the latest:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Update:**  I'm also getting this error with:

```
@Query("SELECT oe FROM OrderEntity oe WHERE oe.id = :orderProductEntity.id")
OrderEntity findBy(@Param("orderProductEntity") OrderProductEntity orderProductEntity);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot do `:order.inProduction` (or `:foo.bar` in general).  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802798/spring-data-jpa-query-with-parameter-properties).

Answer (score 6):

When you use this:

```
:workstation.workflowProcess
```

You're defining a parameter, so you can't use that notation, but you must use a variable as:

```
:workstation
:workflowProcess
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Actually error is in NamedQuery Syntax ,You cannot do like 
 workflowProcess = :workstation.workflowProcess 
instead it should be like 
 workflowProcess = :workflowProcess

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to set the property nativeQuery to **true**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.id FROM team as t JOIN project AS p ON p.team_id",
 nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpEL in the query! Here is my article about that. This should work:

```
@Repository
 public interface JobSetRepository extends JpaRepository<JobSetEntity, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE JobSetEntity SET workstation = :workstation, workflowProcess = :#{#workstation.workflowProcess} WHERE id = :#{#jobSet.id}")
    public Boolean updateWorkstation(@Param("jobSet") JobSetEntity jobSet, @Param("workstation") Workstation workstation);
```

https://dev.to/tolgee_i18n/using-param-object-in-spring-data-jpa-query-poe