# Named query with JPA TREAT is not working due to unexpected AST node

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql, named-query

I am trying to create a named query which is giving error.

```
" SELECT p FROM Project p  " +
" JOIN FETCH p.employees e " +
" WHERE p.id=:id AND ( TREAT(e AS FullTimeEmployee).code = :code OR e.state=:state)"
```

Project Class

```
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String code;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employee> employees;
```

Now Employee class has been extended by multiple classes. The objective of the named query to fetch one project  with filtered employees which have some specific state or FullTimeEmployee with specific code.

Error :

```
<May 2, 2019 12:22:21,205 PM CEST> <Error> <org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter> <BEA-000000> <<AST>:1:127: unexpected AST node: (
<AST>:1:127: unexpected AST node: (
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4936)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExprLhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5370)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4831)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1263)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4552)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HQL unexpected AST node: :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964857/hql-unexpected-ast-node)

Comment: @SudhirOjha  Its not the same as suggested, that is completely different error.

Comment: What versions of JPA and Hibernate are you using?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli hibernate version is 4.2.12.Final and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final

Answer (score 0):

The TREAT function was introduced in JPA 2.1.

Hibernate supports JPA 2.1 from Version 4.3 or 5.0.

So in order to use TREAT you have to update Hibernate.

Comment: Is there any alternative of it which I can use with current dependency as in the project upgrading this will require too much testing.

Comment: When I interpret your query correctly you are only interested in FullTimeEmployee, right? If yes just select ... from FullTimeEmployee

Comment: no, I am interested in all employees having state = active and all the FullTimeEmployee having code = "INT" even if their state is not active

Comment: You could create a query with a UNION