# I am using Spring Jpa Repository to perform all database operations. I don't know how to select a specific value from my table without using any query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My entity class is here:

```
public class ClientDetails {

public ClientDetails() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="serialno")
public int serialno;
@Column(name="gstnum")
public int GSTnum;
@Column(name="bunk_name")
public String bunk_name;
@Column(name="mobile_num")
public int mobile_num;
@Column(name="password")
public String password;
public int getSerialno() {
    return serialno;
}
public void setSerialno(int serialno) {
    this.serialno = serialno;
}
public int getGSTnum() {
    return GSTnum;
}
public void setGSTnum(int gSTnum) {
    GSTnum = gSTnum;
}
public String getBunk_name() {
    return bunk_name;
}
public void setBunk_name(String bunk_name) {
    this.bunk_name = bunk_name;
}
public int getMobile_num() {
    return mobile_num;
}
public void setMobile_num(int mobile_num) {
    this.mobile_num = mobile_num;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

I want to select gstnum from my table based on my bunk_name.I don't want any native query like i did for gstnum in my jpa repository.

> SELECT gstnum from pbm.client_details where bunk_name = 'yoga';

**MY JPA REPOSITORY is**

```
public interface ClientDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientDetails,Integer> {
public static final String gst_num = "SELECT * FROM pbm.client_details;";
//public static final String login_access = "SELECT * FROM clien_details WHERE gstnum pbm.client_details;";

@Query(value = gst_num, nativeQuery = true)
List<ClientDetails> getGstnum();
}
```

Comment: You'll need a query. It doesn't need to be native, though. How about learning JPQL? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql. And how about learning and respecting the Java naming conventions, while you're at it? And avoiding public fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data JPA query with parameter properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802798/spring-data-jpa-query-with-parameter-properties)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@Query` but Spring Data would result not having too

```
@Query("SELECT GSTnum FROM ClientDetails where bunk_name = :callMeSomething")
List<ClientDetails> getGstnum(@Param("callMeSomething") String callMeSomething);
```

How a look here [JPA Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)