# Spring JPA - unexpected AST node

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I started a project to learn Spring Data JPA. This query is to retrieve all `Contract` that are associated with a Profile in the database.

The requirement is that the search criteria needs to be dynamic: there could be either empty, null or a value, this line is an example to build such a statement:

`(?1 is null or ?1 = '' or (p.fullname like %?1% and c.borrowerId = p.id))`

But when execute, I ran into an error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node`

This is the query that I'm trying to execute, could someone explain why the code got the error above? The query can execute successfully if I set `nativeQuery = true`, but error if I try to use HQL syntax.

Here is the query:

```
@Query(value = "select c from Contract c, Profile p where \n" +
"(?1 is null or ?1 = '' or (p.fullname like %?1% and c.borrowerId = p.id)) and \n" +
"(?2 is null or ?2 = '' or (p.phone like (select phone where p.phone like %?2% and p.id = c.borrowerId group by p.phone))) \n" +
"and (?3 is null or ?3 = '' or c.createdDate >= ?3) and (?4 is null or ?4 = '' or c.createdDate <= ?4) " + "and (?5 is null or ?5 = '' or c.status = ?5) ")
Page<Contract> findContractsWithOptionalParameters(String name, String phone, Date startDate, Date endDate, String status, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Look at the second answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802798/spring-data-jpa-query-with-parameter-properties - it might be easier to read than what you have :-).

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: I have tried to rewrite the query which is to avoid the nested select clause. It's working as expected now. I'm going to close the question.