# Is there a way to build a query on runtime based on runtime argument in JPA. I am using Interface which extends JPA Repository. Check body

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<String, String> {

    @Query(value="Select name from **dbname**.Employee where salary>:salary",nativeQuery=true)
    public List<String> getNames(@Param(value = "salary") int salary);
}
```

Now, I want to set this dbname on runtime based in passed runtime arguments. Is there a way to do this?

I am asking this because, We have different regions in which we can test the application.In every region table name is same but database name changes based on region.

Suppose I have four regions namely A,B,C and D
Now, If I pass A as the argument, the query should become 
"Select name from A.Employee where Salary>:salary"

Similarly,If I pass B as argument, the query becomes
"Select name from B.Employee where Salary>:salary"

And so on.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802798/spring-data-jpa-query-with-parameter-properties

Comment: I dont want to put parameters in Predicate part (Part after where statement), I want to set database (schema) name based on runtime argument

Comment: For Eg. 
If an argument is google. Then dbname will be replaced by google and query becomes 
Select name from google.Employee where salary>:salary

If an argument is fb. Then dbname will be replaced by google and query becomes 
Select name from fb.Employee where salary>:salary

Comment: Modified query, had earlier misplaced dbname

Comment: Do you want to change database dynamically?

Comment: Yes. schema name to be exact.

Comment: Can you use multiple entities? Or JDBC itself and use a ResultSetMapper?

Comment: I dont think that will solve the example, Can you give me an example?