# Use @Param as object in JPQL @Query annotation query for multiple parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

We pass `@Param` as for multiple parameters but I want to use single object and fetch

```java
Query("SELECT a FROM Author a WHERE firstName = :firstName AND lastName = :lastName")
List<Author> findByFirstNameAndLastName(@Param("lastName") String firstName, @Param("firstName") String lastName);}
```

I want to use

```java
@Query("SELECT a FROM Author a WHERE firstName = :author.firstName AND lastName = :author.lastName")
List<Author> findByFirstNameAndLastName(@Param("Author") Author author);}
```

Comment: Examine Querydsl.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802798/spring-data-jpa-query-with-parameter-properties if you're using spring.