# How can I use values from class in @query?

Tags: java, sql, rest

**Hi,**

I'm creating Rest API and here is my question.
For example I have @Query like this.

```
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO table(customer, date_of_loading, date_of_unloading")
        "VALUES ('BrandA', '02.02.2022', '03.02.2022',", nativeQuery = true)

void createNewOrder(OrderDto orderId);
```

And how can I take values from my class OrderDto and send it to the @query?

I have also other question where I'm sending just a single word for example and here I just have to use ':orderId' to use incomming String but have no idea how to use it with incomming class. Any ideas?

```
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO table (customer) VALUES (:orderId) ", nativeQuery = true)

void createNewUser(@Param("orderId") String orderId);
```

I just wanna use for example also this same but from OrderDto class like userDto.getCustomer

I know that I can manually send it all 1by1 to the function like:

```
  void createNewUser(@Param("orderId") String orderId, @Param("test") String test, @Param("customer") String customer, );
```

and then use it by :orderId, :test, :customer etc. but take a lot of time and place in code :)

Any ideas :D???

```
@Query(
    value= "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`=?1 AND `age`=?2",
    nativeQuery = true
)
UserEntity findUser(String userName, Integer userAge);
```

Can u somehow use this same like:

```
@Query(
    value= "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`=user.name AND `age`=user.age",
    nativeQuery = true
)
UserEntity findUser(User user);
```

Answer (score 0):

to the best of my knowledge, you do have spread them as a param to the function but why you don't you want to use JPA methods like save() to just implement this instead of the custom queries. but you can take a look at this implementation here

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: This query was just a example. In my API i will have more advanced queries and I have to do it as a query cause JPA methods are not enought unfortunately for me

Comment: ok i think you can do that using the class object as a params pls check this link out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802798/spring-data-jpa-query-with-parameter-properties

Comment: Thank you, my friend