# Using an object instead of single parameters in JPA/JPQL @Param @Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

When doing querys you can do this syntax:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT v from DBTABLE v WHERE v.param1 = param1 AND v.param2 = param2")
List<Result> search(@Param("param1") String param1, @Param("param2") String param2)
```

What if I had more then 2 parameters. Lets say I had 20 parameters, is there a way to give an object instead and refer to the object properties instead? What I mean is this:

Pseudocode:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT v from DBTABLE v WHERE v.param1 = object.param1 AND v.param2 = object.param2")
List<Result> search(@Param("Object") SomeCustomObject object)
```

Comment: I guess, there's nothing on that link about my question.

Comment: I see, I thought it would be implied, but I found that is quite similar to what you are looking for. Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28993810/16034206

Comment: That's the exact thing I was looking for, thank you. You can post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data JPA has SpEL support that provides access to the query method arguments. This allows you to either simply bind the parameter as is or perform additional operations before binding.

This lets you write queries such as:

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.age = ?#{[0]}")
List<User> findUsersByAge(int age);

@Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :#{#customer.firstname}")
List<User> findUsersByCustomersFirstname(@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```

For more details, [see also](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)